# How can I open a set of files in sublime based on their contents

Tags: command-line, search, grep, sublime-text-2

I am trying to find all the files that contain a search term:

`grep -lir "Search" .`

and pipe that into sublime:

`grep -lir "Search" . | subl`

but all this does is open a single file in sublime containing all the search results file paths as lines in the file. What I would like is to open each of those files as a sublime project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the command `subl $(grep -lir "Search" .)` will give you the expected output. The `$(command)` expands with the output of the command and gives it as input to the sublime command. More information can be found in the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

Answer (score 4):

Just use `xargs`:

```
grep -lir "Search" . | xargs subl
```